# Implementing a public API

Tags: java, api, architecture, spring-mvc

Soon I will have to implement a public API (web API). One of the requests will be that we will need to provide different methods to do the same (for example, REST and SOAP), my initial approach is as this.

Make a Controller for the REST
Make a Controller for the SOAP

Use a common Facade class that will handle requests from the REST and the SOAP interface, the Facade class will be in charge of accessing the internals of the system (directly or indirectly, dome DAOs could be used...etc).

Code will be written in Java, most likely will use Spring-MVC among other techs.

Question here is. Does this make sense to you? Is it too absurd? Do you feel any over-architecture here? Any suggestions/experiences/best practices?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I'm doing the same thing,  I use spring-mvc controller for REST request and SOAP request, the service classes are just same, in a controller I use different paths to distinguish REST request and SOAP request.

Comment: How do you handle versioning (different api versions?)

Comment: Sorry, I gave a wrong comment, actually I use spring-mvc and spring-ws, so the soap request go to my Endpoint class, NOT controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach makes sense to me. Spring MVC on its own can handle the REST endpoints, accepting and returning XML and/or JSON. For SOAP, you will need an additional framework like [Spring-WS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/) or [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/).

When using the MVC pattern, it is always best to keep your Controllers as small as possible, by delegating any real work to other beans injected into the controller. These other beans often follow the Service or Repository sterotypes (using Domain Driven Design terminology). These Service and Repository beans can be re-used across REST and SOAP endpoints. I think this is what you mean in your third paragraph, if that is the case then you are on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Does this make sense to you?

Yes.

Is it too absurd?

No.

Do you feel any over-architecture here?

No.

Any suggestions/experiences/best practizes?

You can find design patterns describing what you are doing. For instance, the [GoF adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) says: "In computer programming, the adapter pattern (often referred to as the wrapper pattern or simply a wrapper) is a design pattern that translates one interface for a class into a compatible interface." You have the App Controller (adaptee) that it is  specialized (adaptor) in two interfaces: REST and SOAP.